# Android SQLite Query: Trouble with WHERE clause

Tags: android, where-clause, sqlite

Please let me know why my where clause isn't working. I tried using the query instead of rawquery but no luck.

```
    try {
        String categoryex = "NAME";
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        MyData = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c = MyData.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + where Category = '+categoryex'" , null);
        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Category"));
                    String age = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Text_Data"));
                    results.add(  firstName + " Directions: " + age);
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            } 
        }           
    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        if (MyData != null) 
            MyData.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            MyData.close();
    }
```

Comment: use query. log your exceptions. post your expected / actual results

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try... (you left out a double-quote before `where`.

```
Cursor c = MyData.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " where Category = '" +categoryex + "'" , null);
```

Comment: thanks. for me i used "where Category == value" - 2 mistakes, a) should used single equal sign, and also did not wrap value with a single quote.

Answer (score 9):

I think you should use `rawQuery` in this form:

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ? where Category = ?", new String[] {tableName, categoryex});
```

I think it's more secure this way.

Answer (score 2):

Your quotes are buggered:

```
Cursor c = MyData.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " where Category = '" + categoryex + "'" , null);
```

You also should read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :) I appreciate your help. Had been digging this one for quite sometime. I wish I could accept all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

it will be more easy if you use this technique instead of rawQuery,its easy way change your table name, columns and where conditions accordingly.

```
 public ArrayList<Invitees> getGroupMembers(String group_name) {

    ArrayList<Invitees> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {COLUMN_CONTACT, COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER};

    String selection = COLUMN_GROUP_NAME + "=?";

    String[] selectionArgs = {group_name};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(GROUPS_TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            Invitees invitees = new Invitees();

            invitees.setUserName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_CONTACT)));

            invitees.setInviteePhone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER)));

            contacts.add(invitees);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    return contacts;
}
```